# Seeing the error - "[match] query malformed, no start_object after query name" not sure why

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch

This is the error I am seeing in my AWS Console:

```json
{
  "type": "x_content_parse_exception",
  "reason": "[1:38] [bool] failed to parse field [should]",
  "caused_by": {
    "type": "parsing_exception",
    "reason": "[match] query malformed, no start_object after query name",
    "line": 1,
    "col": 38
  }
}
```

My query formation below:

```js
const result = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(pBody.body));

const { body } = await client.search({
  index: 'first-entry',
  body: {
    query: {
      bool: {
        should: [
          {
            match: result
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
});
```

The result looks like this in the AWS console:

```json
{ "hello": "World!" }
```

So it's just a normal Object? I've tried a number of things to try and get around this error but not having any luck. Does anyone see a problem with how it is formed?

Comment: Could it be that `result` is a string, not an object? a match query expects an object where key is going to be the field name and value is either a string or a match query.

Comment: Well, its input as an object and the AWS console seems to recognise it as an object also? I can play around with the inputs a bit more and see, but a little confused as to why it would be recognising it as a String instead

Comment: It's just a wild guess. The query itself looks alright, so I'm trying to eliminate potential causes.

Comment: The ```result```  comes from my JSON input using postman, formatted very simply as ```{ "hello": "World!" }``` so I assume its actually being passed through as an object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason I was seeing this error was because, although I was correctly doing a `JSON.parse()`, I was stringifying the `result` immediately after.

The Client did not like the stringified result.

To fix this I just made sure the result was parsed and not stringified.